# how to make interrupt every 6hrs

Tags: c++, c, embedded, mbed

For my data logger project , I must store temperature values at every 6 hrs. I observe that ticker maximum time is 30 mins. Is there any way we can make interrupt at long duaration like 6hrs or 10hrs??.

thank you.

Comment: Any way? There are *many* ways. If your system already has a central I/O loop, look there first, as that is likely to have a facility like that already.

Comment: One possibility: put pour interrupt interval to say one minute and count yourself.

Answer (score 2):

So you can make an interrupt every 30 minutes. If there was only a way to ignore every 11 interrupts in a row and handle only the 12th one..

```
volatile int interruptCounter = 0;
void interruptFunction (void)
{
    interruptCounter++;
    if(interruptCounter == 12)
    {
        interruptcounter = 0;
        /*
          Do your stuff here
        */
    }
}
```

Why 12? Because you can handle interrupt occurring every 0.5h. So for handling it every 6h max counter value will be 6/0.5=12, for 10h it will be 10/0.5=20 and so on.

Comment: Good: +1. But `volatile` here does not make much sense. A local scoped `static uint8_t` can be fine. And check `>=` always better instead of `==`.

Comment: @LPs You are right with the `volatile`, this make sense only when variable is used both inside and outside interrupt function. It is some kind of habit for me to use `volatile` inside interrupt functions :). And you are right with `>=` check but in this case i don't see any way to "miss" `interruptCounter == 12` checking.